# Is there a .gitconfig option that corresponds to the git status --ignore-submodules setting?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there a global .gitconfig setting that allows to change the default of the ignore-submodules option from "all" to "dirty", "untracked", or "none"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [git config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

`diff.ignoreSubmodules` is supposed to override any '`submodule.<name>.ignore`' settings.
And it sets the default value of the `--ignore-submodules` command-line option.

However, [Allan Jensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11405014/allan-jensen) reports (in 2019, nine years later) that feature as not working, and [proposes a patch](https://public-inbox.org/git/4489241.31r3eYUQgx@twilight/), shown [in this diff](https://public-inbox.org/git/4489241.31r3eYUQgx@twilight/2-fix-ignoreSubmodule.diff).

Comment: How does that look in the config file? When I use "git config --global" it doesn't seem to write anything to my ~/.gitconfig file. Typing "git status" still shows submodules with -dirty at the end.

Comment: hmm, seems like i've got it set up correctly but git status still shows dirty submodules. i type that on the project level by the way. do i need to do it on the submodule level also?

Comment: @twig: is there some [`git submodule update`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update) missing, before querying any status?

Comment: Nope, they're all clean submodules. I just test by creating a new file or editing an existing file in a submodule (without committing) and it marks the submodule as dirty.

Comment: That does not appear to work. .gitmodules wins over .gitconfig settings, so only option at the moment is using the command-line

Comment: @AllanJensen What version of Git are you using? On which OS?

Comment: Doesn't matter. They are all like that. I send a patch to the git mailing list but got no feedback.

Comment: @AllanJensen OK, I will monitor https://public-inbox.org/git/4489241.31r3eYUQgx@twilight/